# How to get the minimum and maximum closedate from Opportunity object without hitting query limit

Tags: soql, governorlimits

I have a checkbox lightning-input filter on a dashboard that needs to show all quarters that opportunities have been set to close (Q2-2023, Q3-2023, Q4-2023, Q1-2024... etc). Therefore, based on User Level row permissions, I need to grab the minimum and maximum closedate to calculate this range.

Every SOQL method I have tried will always hit the 50,000 row limit.

1. `SELECT CALENDAR_YEAR(closedate), CALENDAR_QUARTER(closedate) FROM opportunity GROUP BY CALENDAR_YEAR(closedate), CALENDAR_QUARTER(closedate)`
2. `SELECT min(closedate), max(closedate) FROM Opportunity`
3. `[SELECT closedate FROM Opportunity ORDER BY closedate DESC][0]`

Is there any alternative way to grab these two values w/o hitting the 50K limit? I was wondering if I should explore batch apex and save the two values in metadata, but then those two values don't abide to User Level row permissions, so I'm worried it will fail security review (ex. a user sees Q1-2023 on the checklist but doesn't have opps in that Q, only other users in the org do. They wouldn't be able to see those Q1-2023 opps, but they gain knowledge that opps exist in Q1-2023 within the org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, when you use the aggregate functions MIN, MAX, AVG, or SUM, every row in the query counts against the limits. If you're really just after the min or max, you can always just use an order by with a limit:

```
Opportunity minDate = [SELECT CloseDate FROM Opportunity ORDER BY CloseDate ASC LIMIT 1];
Opportunity maxDate = [SELECT CloseDate FROM Opportunity ORDER BY CloseDate DESC LIMIT 1];
```

As a bonus, these queries leverage indexes, and so are very quick. Of course, it's generally a bad practice to do this inside of a trigger or other batched operation, but for a UI widget, the performance will be acceptable.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that the ORDER BY happens before the LIMIT is applied, I was originally thinking that LIMIT 1 would first be applied to a random row, and then it would order it.